# Fusion 360 M3D Slicer

Tags: 3d-models, 3d-design, software, slicing

I have created a design with fusion 360. I tried to print it with my M3D Pro printer but it seems the designs have a flaw.

If I try to print the bottom part, the second layer is wrong. It seems to have moved to the left by a few centimeters.

Here is the link to the `.stl` files and pictures of how the first few layers turned out.

https://seafile.fmk.me/d/09e43aa7fc8e416ab187/

[image: broken print]
[image: broken print 2]
[image: bottom.stl]
[image: top.stl]

The `bottom.stl` file can be loaded and viewed in the m3d software but leads to faulty print after the first layer. The `top.stl` cannot even be viewed in the M3D software.

Other 3D files from thingiverse etc. can be printed without a problem.
Do I need to enable any special features to be able to print those files correctly?

Yours, Felix

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the "bottom" and "top" stl.  An stl file is usually for the whole object, not only one layer.  Is your last paragraph two questions, a single statement followed by a question.  I find it confusing.    Also, I think it is possible to embed pictures within your question.  Doing so will let more peiple view them, since many (including me) are reluctant to open an unknown, uncontrolled site.

Comment: Bottom and top are two parts of a full enclosure that i try to print.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently my x belt and/or my x motor is broken. Getting replacement parts fixing the problem!

Comment: Whilst your answer is presumably correct - seeing that you are answering your own question :-) - could you expand upon it a little? By _broken_ what exactly was the problem? Worn belt, loose belt, missing teeth, worn motor, faulty motor, etc? What exactly did you have to change to resolve the problem? Was it the belt, OR the motor OR both? If you could kindly update your answer, it _may_ provide invaluable help for other people who are experiencing the same problems that you were experiencing. Thanks.

Comment: A gear or the connection of the gear to the motor broke and slipped on some of the movements. The printer is currently in repair so that the status!

Answer (score 1):

FMK, I loaded the two STL files, top.stl and bottom.stl into Meshmixer. Using Analysis, Inspector, no errors were found in the models. I then loaded the STL files into my slicer, Simplify3D. Due to common Y/Z exchange, the models were loaded in a vertical orientation. It was simple enough to use "Place surface on bed" to get things "squared up."

The g-code preview showed also no failure points.

My first suggestion would be to ensure that you have your model flat to the bed. I've run into too many Thingiverse models that the creator made with a non-zero planar reference, that is, the model was tilted a few degrees.

You say that you created the model in Fusion 360, which would imply that your model is square to the plane.

I'm not familiar with M3D software, but if you have the option to use a different slicer, use Slic3r or Cura to see if you have the same results.

As it stands, I'd consider no fault in the model files.

Comment: Thanks for the checking of my model files, since im am rotating the files in the m3d software myself i need to check if it is sitting plane on the ground.